# nlog configuration for logstash

Tags: logstash, nlog

Assume a system of about 20 producers generating application diagnostic data (logs), each using the following NLog logstash target configuration:

```xml
    <!-- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Network-target -->
    <target xsi:type="Network" name="logstash"
            address="tcp://logstash-server:port"
            newLine="true"
            maxMessageSize="65000" onOverflow="Discard"
            connectionCacheSize="5" keepConnection="True" KeepAliveTimeSeconds="30" >
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
        ...
      </layout>
    </target>
```

I have the following considerations and your opinion would be appreciated:

- Would it make sense to wrap the logstash target with `BufferingWrapper`? Will this result in one giant message, possibly exceeding the `maxMessageSize`?
- Or is it better to use the `AsyncWrapper` for some reason?
- Given that 20 producers each hold 5 connections, are there any TCP limits which can be hit?

I would like to start with strong coupling first and only later consider logging to log files which are then shipped to logstash. Any useful references or github examples for larger projects are also appreciated.

References:

https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target

Answer (score 0):

Based on the how the Network target works I think there is no need for any wrappers. The network target already contains a queue which can drop messages when full. So at the moment the following is a reasonable configuration to start with:

```xml
    <!-- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Network-target -->
    <!-- TCP protocol must be used and newLine is critical -->
    <target xsi:type="Network" name="logstash"
            address="tcp://logstash-server:port"
            newLine="true"
            maxMessageSize="65000" onOverflow="Discard"
            maxQueueSize="10000"
            connectionCacheSize="5" keepConnection="True" KeepAliveTimeSeconds="30" >
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
        ...
      </layout>
    </target>
```